# make a subdirectory public

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have a web site which is protected with basic authentication
I need to make a sub directory public.
Tried using  but it ended in error 500 - server error
Also tried using separated .htaccess files, but as the files higher up the chain can't be overridden, that didn't work as well...
any suggestions?

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Welcome to the VIP area :P"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasses
require valid-user
```

the code above works fine, but when I add the following:

```
<Location /private/folder >
Allow from All
Satisfy Any
</Location>
```

it crashes into error 500

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your webserver error log?

Comment: I don't have access to the error log file, I'm just a student using school server...

Comment: In that case, can you post the contents of your `.htaccess` files?

Comment: there it is in the main post

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you defined your directories permissions but using 'other' could be a good idea.
If you have you primary directory, let say /www/, with permission XX1, then any user will be able to go through it without problems and reach your subdirectory you want to be public.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `<Location>` directives aren't permitted in `.htaccess` files (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667894/httaccess-location-not-allowed-here).  The server will be writing a message into its error log that reads

```
/path/to/.htaccess: <Location not allowed here
```

You should be able to nest a `<Files>` directive inside your `<Directory>` block (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files).

Comment: tried the <Files> the error 500 is gone, but I still can't access the file publicly...

Comment: now it looks like:
`<Files "/path/to/www/www/public/folder/index.php">
  Allow from All
  Satisfy Any
 </Files>`